# Seriously customized iOS

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

Couple of days ago I flew through JFK and they had iPad's for travelers with several interesting features:

- Most of default applications are gone (no Settings, Calendar, Camera, Photos, Video, Notes, AppStore etc)
- Installed application can't be deleted (if I press and hold an icon - nothing happens)

I know that some apps could be hidden using Restriction payload in a configuration profile (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW13)

However, I don't know how to

- Hide apps like Calendar and Settings
- Prevent uninstallation of all apps

Do you know how programmatically do this? Do they use some private configuration profile settings or do they use some custom firmware provided by Apple?

**Update 1**

Ok. I just found how to prevent uninstallation. You can go to settings->Restriction and uncheck "Deleting Apps".

Comment: If they hid builtin apps, it's either custom from Apple or jailbroken.

Comment: If it was in some cafe, jailbreak was quite possible, but I am not sure that airport IT will be jailbreaking devices.

Answer (score 2):

Some companies can get special permission from Apple to do specific things, but they have to have a valid reason and it has to be approved. The JFK deployment was an Enterprise deployment and you can't buy the apps from the App Store.

I also know that the ones going in LA Public Schools are modified specifically for the school requirements.

Basically unless you have a hell of a reason, you are not going to be able to do this.

Comment: I happened to interview for the JFK position at the company that does it and I read the info about the LA Public Schools. These are custom Apple configurations.

Comment: Do you mean it's special configuration profiles or special iOS firmware prepared for these companies.

Comment: I never went that far with them to know the details. My understanding is that they had to contact apple and let them know they want something special done. I believe they gave them an acces to a SDK Library to be able to make their modifications and they had to code it.  I have heard this happen about 3 or 4 seperate times but I have never personally embarked on doing it.

Comment: There was one company that specialized in Secure SMS using iPhones and they had a point person at Apple that approved this for enterprise use. They still had to code it but somehow they were approved for it.

Comment: I know that Apple provides additional entitlements for some companies who wants to write VPN clients. However, I believe all they do are providing special provisioning profile which includes this entitlement. I haven't heard about any involvement deeper than this.